# Why type_traits are classes & not functions

Tags: c++, type-traits

I have been looking into `type_traits` recently & was wondering why are they implemented as `class templates` whereas implementing them as `functions` could be more obvious & have a simpler syntax.

What I want to say is this syntax :-

```
int x = 5;
std::cout << is_same<int>(x);
```

Is more convincing & cleaner than the actual one ie :-

```
int x = 5;
std::cout << is_same <int, decltype(x)>::value;
```

This is just a case of curiosity. I just want to know the philosophy of the Standardization Committee in preferring the `class` method over the `function` method.

Comment: Using a function doesn't give you a compile-time constant value in C98, making a normal function less useful.

Comment: `<type_traits>` is all about template metaprogramming, and in metaprogramming a function is actually a class: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time_function_execution

Comment: @zahir "in metaprogramming a function is actually a class", could you enlighten me on this

Comment: It is called meta-function actually. If my previous link to Wikipedia and related pages did not work for you, you may want to read through some tutorials here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. **Versality**. Most type traits have both `X::value` boolean constant and `X::type` type alias which can be used for tag dispatch.
2. **Ability to partially specialize**. You cannot have partial specialization for function, only full specializations and overloads. It is easy to call wrong function in presence of both specializations and overloads.
3. **Compile-time evaluation**. Most of type traits were invented in previous millenia, when `constexpr` functions were not avaliable. Even in constexpr functions you cannot pass values as parameter, as it might prevent compile-time evaluation.
4. **You always have type**, but sometimes it is all you have. Creating a function which does not work all the time is counterproductive, so we will not be able to rely on template parameter deduction anyway.